# Convergence of Random Series

Tags: probability, inequality

Let's say you have $X_1, X_2, ....$ independent real valued random variables and let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$. Do you know how we can show that $P(\sup_{n\geq 1} |S_n| > 4\epsilon) \leq 4 \sup_{n\geq 1} P( |S_n| > \epsilon)$?

Comment: What's the big deal with $4$??

Comment: I am not sure as I can't prove it yet.

Comment: My analysis is rusty. Any success if you replace $\sup |S_n| > 4 \varepsilon$ by $\sup S_n^2 > 16 \varepsilon$ and $|S_n| > \varepsilon$ by $S_n^2 > \varepsilon$? (this is an equivalent question) I think I remember that moments are usually better understood than absolute values of random variables.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788647/maximal-inequality-for-sums-of-independent-random-variables) recent post, as well as [Etemadi's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etemadi's_inequality) mentioned therein. In the linked post, there is no 4 on the right hand side. Are you sure about your version? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Ian: This is rather trivial if you remove the 4 from the right hand side.  In Etemadi's inequality as you link to it, it has 3 on both sides

Comment: @user149644 Perhaps you could think of a title which is more appropriate. Your question has nothing to do with convergence of random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it suffices, by the continuity of the measure, to show that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{k \leq n} |S_k|>4 \varepsilon \right) \leq 4 \sup_{k \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_k|> \varepsilon)$$

for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This inequality follows from Etemadi's inequality:

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{k \leq n} |S_k|>4 \varepsilon \right) &\leq \mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{k \leq n} |S_k|>3 \varepsilon \right) \\ &\leq 3\sup_{k \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_k|>\varepsilon) \\ &\leq 4 \sup_{k \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_k|>\varepsilon). \end{align*}$$

> **Etemadi's inequality** Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables. For $S_n := \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$, we have $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{k \leq n} |S_k| > 3 \varepsilon \right) \leq 3 \sup_{k \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_k|>\varepsilon).$$